# PhoneGap - get started in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-2012, cordova, windows-7-x64

I have complete project in Visual Studio and I want it wrap to PhoneGap. I can't install PhoneGap, when I am writing to command line this: npm install -g phonegap, so I get this:

```
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Marek
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Marek\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code0
```

I installed Git GUI in: C:\Users\Marek, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `git` the command line version to do this. The GUI version(I don't know which one that is) probably won't work. Get it from here: http://git-scm.com/
You should be able to type git and not get an error on the command line before you use npm

Comment: I download Git-1.9.4-preview20140611 and install to  C:\Users\Marek, but same reaction.

Comment: if you type git on cmd, what message do you get?

Comment: When I run a git and I click on Git Bash, so I get:

Welcome to Git (version 1.9.4-preview20140611)
Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

Marek@FALEXPC-PC ~ (master)
$

If you think this

Comment: did u try to run npm in the git bash

Comment: That was the problem. I don't understand it, because before I was trying exploit  this advice and I got some errors. Thank you so much for your advices and your time.